# Lost all my files on Openrefine

Tags: openrefine, google-refine

I tried de beta version of Openrefine and now I have lost all my previous files on the version 2.5. Do you know where the files are located? I am on Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The project directory location changed between the 2.5 and 2.6 version
and has been renamed from `./Google/Refine` to `./OpenRefine`

If you run both versions, add a property a definition for refine.data_dir using a line like this in the refine.ini for your Google Refine 2.5 installation

`JAVA_OPTIONS=-Drefine.data_dir=/path/to/data/dir`

You can read more of in the [2.6-beta release note](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/releases/tag/2.6-beta.1).

Comment: mmm, it doesn't work for me. I can't find the right path.